# Two User Inputs Are Different but Program Recognizes Them as the Same

Tags: java, while-loop, equals

I am creating a program that will later compare two files together. I created two while loops that check whether user inputed files are the right file type, have a valid pathway to them, and are normal files. The first while loop checks the first inputed file (called initialFile) and the second while loop checks the second inputed file (called compareFile). The second while loop check also checks to make sure that comparefile is different from the initialFile.

The problem I am running in to is when I tested if the second while loop check catches an identical file type input. The second while loop correctly does not end if the file type is wrong, there is not a valid pathway to the file, or if it is not a normal file but if I input a file for compareFile that is identical to initialFile the while loop ends when it should loop.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.Exception;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class QuickSortAnagram {


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    String initialInput = " ";

    String compareInput = " ";

    //Check to make sure FIRST user input is the correct file type, is a valid file pathway, and is a normal file

    /*while loop requires user to input a String that ends with ".txt" before
     *the loop will end. This ensures that the user will input a String
     *that represents the correct file type before being allowed to move on.
     The while loop also requires that the user input a filename that has 
     a valid pathway to it and is a normal file or the user will not be allowed to move on*/

    boolean initialWhileLoopEnd = false;

    while(initialWhileLoopEnd == false) {

     System.out.println("Enter initial test file (Please make sure it is in the form 'textfile.txt', that there is a valid pathway to file, and that file is normal or program will not be able to continue): ");
     initialInput = scnr.next();

     File initialFile = new File(initialInput);

     if(initialInput.endsWith(".txt")) {
       if(initialFile.isFile()) {
         initialWhileLoopEnd = true;
       }
       else {
         System.out.println("File does not exist and/or is not a normal file");
       }
      }
     else {
     System.out.println("Invalid file type");
     }
    }

    //initializes file outside of while loop so it can be read later
    File initialFile = new File(initialInput);


    //Check to make sure SECOND user input is the correct file type, is a valid file pathway, is a normal file, and is not the same file name that user used for the FIRST check

    /*while loop requires user to input a String that ends with ".txt" before
     *the loop will end. This ensures that the user will input a String
     *that represents the correct file type before being allowed to move on.
     The while loop also requires that the user input a filename that has 
     a valid pathway to it and is a normal file or the user will not be allowed to move on*/

    boolean compareWhileLoopEnd = false;

     while(compareWhileLoopEnd == false) {

     System.out.println("Enter compare test file (Please make sure it is in the form 'textfile.txt', that there is a valid pathway to file, that file is normal, and that file is not identical to the initial file inputed or program will not be able to continue): ");
     compareInput = scnr.next();

     File compareFile = new File(compareInput);

     if(compareInput.endsWith(".txt")) {
       if(compareFile.isFile()) {
         if(compareFile != initialFile) {
         compareWhileLoopEnd = true;
         }
         else {
           System.out.println("File is identical to the initial file inputed. Please input a different file");
         }
       }
       else {
         System.out.println("File does not exist and/or is not a normal file");
       }
      }
     else {
     System.out.println("Invalid file type");
     }
    }

     File compareFile = new File(compareInput);

    scnr.close();
  } 
}
```

Why is my while loop ending when it should be looping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just look at your code:

```
if (compareFile != initialFile) {
    compareWhileLoopEnd = true;
}
```

So, if the second File object is not the same object as the first File object (which is **always** the case), you end the loop.

It should instead be

```
if (compareFile.equals(initialFile)) {
     System.out.println("File is identical to the initial file inputed. Please input a different file");    }
else {
    compareWhileLoopEnd = true;
}
```

Note that even with the above code, it's not absolutely correct, since the first File could be `foo.txt` and the second could be `../currentDirectory/foo.txt`, which wouldn't be equal, although they both actually refer to the same file on the file system. If you want to catch these kinf of problems, then look at File's javadoc, and see how you can get the absolute path of a file.